# Electrical circuit analogue of a nonlinear pendulum

Tags: electric-circuits, oscillators

Is it possible to make an electrical circuit analogue of a nonlinear pendulum?  To model the equation

$$y'' = -\sin(y)$$

They did this on analog computers in the past, but how? How to model the non-linearity of $\sin(y)$?

Comment: One can, for instance, approximate the sine-function as a Taylor expansion with multipliers ($\sin x \approx x - x^3/3)$ or (probably better) use non-linear diode circuits like this sine shaper: http://www.cntronics.com/editorfiles/20130426155213_5688.gif. The latter are mostly used in analog synthesizers because the voltage controlled oscillators produce triangle waves.

Comment: With _linear_ circuit elements like resistors, capacitors, and inductors, the answer is no, you can not do that... Only approximate it.

Comment: Mostly, nonlinearity is achieved just by sticking any available nonlinear element in there (a diode, for instance). You surely can't achieve the entire sine behaviour (the rotating pendulum mode would mean indefinitely increasing voltage). So you just need an odd function with decreasing slope. Then you just do some fitting to find the right parameters and you're done.

Comment: @orion: There is nothing in the way of modeling cyclical variables with analog systems, one would not use one but a pair of signals, usually denoted $I$ and $Q$ which obey the relationship $I^2+Q^2=1$. In typical implementations these signals are also modulated on a carrier, which allows the use of AC amplifiers (much easier to stabilize against drift than DC circuits) and mixers for precision multiplication (way fewer components than DC multipliers). This is roughly WW II and 1950s technology and it's still in use in modern digital communications algorithms.

Comment: @CuriousOne oh yes, quadrature, it's how analog TV works :) I was thinking of a single signal, though.

Comment: @orion: Don't try to mess with (great)-grandpa's engineering skills... those guys already knew how to do stuff. I have a cool story about that, but it doesn't belong here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

An electrical circuit that has a Josephson junction (JJ) is described by the (modified) pendulum equation. A Josephson junction is a structure that consists of two superconductors separated by a thin layer of an insulator. A JJ operates at low temperatures (~10-30 K), so that the superconductors are in quantum states. The current through the JJ is proportional to $\sin(\phi)$, where $\phi$ is the phase difference of wave-functions of the two superconductors, while the voltage across the JJ $\sim d\phi/dt$, see [Josephson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect#Josephson_phase). The dynamics of an ideal JJ is described by the pendulum-like equation for phase: $\phi_{tt} + \sin(\phi) = 0$, see e.g. [Long Josephson junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Josephson_junction) (taking equation from this Wikipedia article, we ignore damping effects ($\alpha = 0$), the bias current ($\gamma=0$), and consider a point-like JJ (no dependence on $x$).